# Only one default export per module allowed error on React Native with Navbar

Tags: javascript, react-native, error-handling

I'm trying to make a Bottom NavBar with React Native with icons, but I have this error coming up Only one default export allowed per module.
The issue comes from the last line export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);

I tried to do it this way export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator)(Home) and remove the export default to my Home.js component but it's not working either.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. All help will be welcome!

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

import Profile from "./Profile";
import Appointment from "./Appointment";



const styles = StyleSheet.create({

   homeText: {
      fontSize: 40,
      
   },

   homeCont: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center"
   }

})

export default class Home extends Component {

   render() {

      return(

         <View style={styles.homeCont}>
            <Text style={styles.homeText}>HOME SCREEN</Text>
            
         </View>
    
     
      )

   }

   

}

const TabNavigator= createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({

   Home: {screen:Home,
          navigationOptions: {
             tabBarLabel: 'Home',
             activeColor: '#ff0000',
             inactiveColor: '#000000',
             barStyle: {backgroundColor: '#67baf6'},
             tabBarIcon:() => (
                <View>
                   <Icon name={'home'} size={25} style={{color:'#ff000'}} />
                </View>
             )
          }
   },
   Appointment: {screen:Appointment,
      navigationOptions: {
         tabBarLabel: 'Appointment',
         activeColor: '#ff0000',
         inactiveColor: '#000000',
         barStyle: {backgroundColor: '#67baf6'},
         tabBarIcon:() => (
            <View>
               <Icon name={'calendar'} size={25} style={{color:'#ff000'}} />
            </View>
         )
      }
},

Profile: {screen:Profile,
   navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      activeColor: '#ff0000',
      inactiveColor: '#000000',
      barStyle: {backgroundColor: '#67baf6'},
      tabBarIcon:() => (
         <View>
            <Icon name={'person'} size={25} style={{color:'#ff000'}} />
         </View>
      )
   }
}


});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are exporting the Home component `

```
export default class Home extends Component {

   render() {

      return(

         <View style={styles.homeCont}>
            <Text style={styles.homeText}>HOME SCREEN</Text>
            
         </View>
    
     
      )

   }

   

}
```

Instead, do

```
function Home () {
      return(
         <View style={styles.homeCont}>
            <Text style={styles.homeText}>HOME SCREEN</Text>
         </View>
     )

}
```

Comment: Perfect! I did the remove the export default from Home. now I have this error  : This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "route" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation,  which I don't understand, everything seems ok, I don't see where is the error